# What are the requirements for the example question in the site tour?

Tags: support, tour

The site tour uses an example question to illustrate how sites work.  By default, it is a question about preventing unicorns from eating daisies.  I know that it's possible to change that question (some sites have done so) and that there are some pretty strict requirements on candidate questions in order to be used for that.  (On one site where I'm a moderator, following the "edit question" link just leads to a message saying "no eligible questions".)  I believe there is a length limit and that certain formatting is not allowed.

I've searched MSE and checked the moderator-only section of the help center but I can't find the specific requirements.  What are they?  If my site wants to change the tour question, what conditions must our proposed replacement satisfy?

[image: example question in tour]

Comment: Interesting. [startups.se]'s seems to have a non-default one already. I never changed it, and I've never heard of any of my fellow mods doing it either, although they might have. Maybe it automatically changes once one is eligible? I checked, and we only have the one that's listed as eligible, and I definitely see your confusion. It's not a bad question of course, but it isn't near our highest voted, most answered or viewed.

Comment: Ah, i went looking, and found it on [Emacs.SE](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: On [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) the tour question changes quite often: the current one is 8 hours old. I can't imagine that the mods have nothing better to do than keep changing that question. It has to be an automatic process, based on having positive  votes, at least two answers, and comments on one of those answers (necessary to demonstrate the commenting feature).

Comment: @WeaponofChoice interesting.  I thought I'd heard that an eligible question would be auto-chosen if one existed, but I didn't know it kept changing it.  We have no eligible questions and we're getting complaints about the unicorn question; if we knew what the requirements are we could work on getting one of our questions to be eligible.